Commented real line
I'm trying to reproduce the following picture using latex.

What would be the right way to do it?
An attempt follows:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the real line
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
    
    \draw[thick] (2.5,-0.2) -- (2.5,0.2); % This is the vertical marker
    
    % Label the point at the center
    \node[above] at (2.5,0.2) {$c_{l_1}$};

    \draw[thick] (2,0.2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=0.2];
    
    % Label the point at the center
    \node[below] at (2,-0.2) {$c_{l_1} - \epsilon$};
\end{tikzpicture}

Yet I am not very convinced about the curvature of the open interval.

This is not super hard to do in tikz, but you need to show what you have so far? Otherwise your question is a please do this for me question and those questions are generally frowned upon.

Remember full minimal example, not sniplets where we have to add stuff in order to try the code,

Here is something to play with. It can be done in various ways.
\documentclass[a4paper,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\Angle{7}
  \def\Radius{1} % radius of epsilon circle
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (E) at (6,0);
  \coordinate (D) at ($(O)!0.5!(E)$);
  % two points for the epsilon markings, we draw them later as circle args
  \coordinate (I1) at ($(D)+({180-\Angle}:\Radius)$);
  \coordinate (I2) at ($(D)+({0+\Angle}:\Radius)$);
  \coordinate (L) at ($(O)!0.2!(E)$);
  \coordinate (R) at ($(O)!0.8!(E)$);
  \draw (O) -- (E);
  \draw ($(D)+(0,0.15)$) -- ++(0,-0.3) node [below] {$d$};
  \draw ($(L)+(0,0.1)$) -- ++(0,-0.2);
  \draw ($(R)+(0,0.1)$)
  coordinate (Rt) node[above right] {$c$}
  -- ++(0,-0.2);
  %\draw (D) circle (\Radius);
  \draw (I1) arc [start angle={180-\Angle},delta angle={2*\Angle},  radius=\Radius=] node[below] {$d-\varepsilon$};
  \draw (I2) arc [start angle={0+\Angle},delta angle={-2*\Angle},  radius=\Radius=] node[below] {$d+\varepsilon$};
  \draw[->] ($(Rt)+(135:0.1)$) .. controls ++(150:0.15) and ++(40:0.15) .. ($(I2)+(45:0.1)$)
  node[pos=0.5,above] {?};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

